# ahk how to pause loop while executing timer?

Tags: autohotkey

How to pause the main loop and press buff keys every min? But main loop autohotkey script seems overriding the timer script at both are running in the same time? How can I make the main loop pause and make priority of timer to run press keys every min?

```
home::
SetTimer, skillbuffs,  60000 ;1min
loop
{
;attack loop and pick items main script
}

skillbuffs:
send{f5} ;press self skill  every1min
SetTimer, skillbuffs,  On
return
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. With your current code the timer will run every minute and then the "main" loop will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

`SetTimer` runs its tasks in parallel with the rest of the script, which is why you're not seeing the loop waiting.

You could include the loop inside the timer, which will force it to wait for the loop to break before completing its tasks, such as the below code:

```
DoTheLoop()
{
StartTime := A_TickCount ; Set current tick time (uptime of PC) to compare against.
loop
{
    ElapsedTime := A_TickCount - StartTime ; Difference between start of loop and now.
    SendInput, %ElapsedTime%{Enter}
    Sleep, 1000
    if ( ElapsedTime >= 10000 ) ; 10.0 sec.
    {
        break
    }
}}

Home::
SetTimer, skillbuffs

skillbuffs:
DoTheLoop()
SendInput, Skillbuffs timer has fired.{Enter}
SetTimer, skillbuffs,  On
return
```

But this is a kludge at best, and thus isn't 100% reliable. That aside, it seems you're over-engineering the problem if you have clearly defined tasks and a timeframe with which to do it.

Instead, I would recommend going simpler:

```
MainLoop()
{
StartTime := A_TickCount ; Set current tick time (uptime of PC) to compare against.
loop
{
    ElapsedTime := A_TickCount - StartTime ; Difference between start of loop and now.

    ; Do stuff in the loop.

    if ( ElapsedTime >= 60000 ) ; 60.0 sec.
    {
        SendInput, {F5} ; Press self skill every 60 sec.
        StartTime := A_TickCount ; Reset StartTime variable.
    }
}}

Home::
MainLoop()
return
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a `Sleep, 10` (Or 100, or whatever duration you feel you can afford) somewhere in your main loop. This will pause the main loop for however many milliseconds, allowing other processes to get run time. This may be especially important if the code is marked `Critical`.

Comment: Nothing in her question indicates that that's her problem and even with an empty loop Autohotkey will not prevent other processes 'getting runtime'.